# How to access Application Settings in Azure Function In Portal C# app function?

Tags: c#, azure, configuration

Trying to access an application setting from an Azure Function create in the portal.

Current issue with ConfgiurationBuilder namespace not being found.

I have ended up with the following code, which seems a bit lengthy for something which is supposed to be encourgaed to be used.

Most only resources that I have found so far refer to Visual  Studio built Azure function using the start up binding.

net core c# function.
Version 2 function.

First - setup setting in function apps Platform Settings / General Settings / Configuration

Then the function code:

- package include for System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
- using added for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
- add ExectuionContext context as paramter

Code looks like this

```cs
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public static async Task<string> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log,
    ExecutionContext context) {

    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
    var app_setting = config["MyAppSetting"];

    return app_setting;
}
```

As mentioned the issues this has

- Does not build due to ConfigurationBuilder namespace not found, despite no error from #r ConfigurtaionManager
- looks a bit lengthy. If startup/dependency used then could be hidden. This is done in portal so maybe some dependency exists to short then?

Comment: So you want  to read the setting in application setting or add settings?

Comment: Why you use local.setting.json on portal? The local.settings.json file stores app settings, connection strings, and settings used by local development tools. Settings in the local.settings.json file are used only when you're running projects locally.

Comment: On portal, app settings is not be saved in local.settings.json. I hope my answer can help you understand.

Comment: @Maze Please try using  `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("appSettingName", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("appSettingName", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Comment: Great, now searching Azure Function Environment Variable gives many results with this answer. Down full of multiple ways of solving same thing. Other answers great, used this a solution due to short and to the point. var app_setting = could be added to make clear of usage.

Answer (score 2):

After you finish a function app and update it to the portal. The value of `local.setting.json` will be under the "Application settings" tab of the published function app in the Azure Portal (see picture). So on the portal, if you want to change appsettings you need to do operate on 'application settings'.

[image]
[image]

So if you want to access app settings, you can use this:

```
var environmentmyDesiredKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyAppSetting");
```

to get the `'MyAppSetting'` that setted in 'application settings'.(Don't forget to `using System.Configuration;`)

[image]

Things works on my side. If you have more questions please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use **GetEnvironmentVariable** like so:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public static async Task<string> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log) {

var app_setting = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyAppSetting");

return app_setting;
```

}